# Is there a new standard web page width? How many pixels?

Tags: html, css, browser

I am just building a new site for a client and want to make sure I serve him best.  I am at the process of determining the page width.

First, for the last few years, my pages have been typically about 900 pixels wide and centered in the middle of the browser window. This works really well.  That's not the approach I am taking now though.  My old standard of 900-1000 pixels seems really small on today's monitors.

I am creating a three column page layout. The leftmost column needs to stick to the left side of the browser.  If the browser is set really wide, there is a huge vertical dead zone on the right side of the browser.  That's not really a problem since I doubt most people open their browser to 100% wide on a 1600px monitor.

My question is this: Is there a standard pixel width that you assume 90% of the people use to view a web site?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

960 pixels!

It has plenty of denominations to allow you to split your page up into various columns. I suggest taking a look at http://960.gs

I know, as you said that it is small compared to your monitor, however there are a lot of users (the majority) who would benefit from keeping this resolution.

Comment: I know fluid width pages are supposedly user friendly but consider sites such as Facebook and Twitter, they have a fixed width layout, no one complains because they 'work'.

Comment: Wow! The 960.gs site has some great examples.  I set my page for 960. I won't use the CSS concept but all of the sites that are displayed are good looking and exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can also consider using a so called "responsive" approach:

http://978.gs/

The idea is that using media queries (and substitute techniques) you adapt your layout to the viewport of your visitor, so ideally you can offer the best content to everyone.

Comment: The responsive approach was cool. I have no need for it though, at least on this project.  I will certainly keep it in mind though. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Wabbitseason, I have always used 960.gs as it has always suited my needs and I haven't had the need to even look for anything else, but I've added the site to my new 'reading list', I'll take a look later!

Answer (score 4):

If you made fluid-width pages, this wouldn't be an issue.

Monitors these days are all over the place.  You will have to check your analytics to see what your particular audience is using.

If I make a fixed-width page, I usually still shoot for 980px.  There are lots of netbooks popping up with resolutions of around 1024x800 and what not.  Again though, there is no specific answer to this question, other than making pages without a fixed-width, or checking your own audience.

Comment: Is this what you are referring to as fluid width: http://css-tricks.com/examples/PerfectFluidWidthLayout/ The line length makes it almost impossible to read much on a page.

Comment: @Evik, don't be so closed minded.  There are plenty of ways to design your site where fluid width works, and limiting line length.  If your page is mostly text, then perhaps a fluid width isn't for you.  In any case, the philosophy on the web is that it isn't really up to you.  The client should be able to render the text in such a way that the client wants.

Comment: Disliking long line length isn't being close minded. It's being realistic. People also have a hard time of reading white on white. It's only an opinion (not really a philosophy) that a site design should be left to the user. Correct me if I am wrong, but you're suggesting that CNN should allow you to change their color, layout, and maybe even content when you visit? I can't imagine that working well.